# Creating popup without possibility to tab to a background element

Tags: c#, windows-8, popup, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to create a popup but when it is open it is still possible to use the tab key to switch the focus to an element in the background (e.g. to a button and use space to press is). The only way I found until now is to check on every lostFocus event (which also fires for every element contained in the Border element) and check if the focus is now in a element inside the Border. If not I manually set the focus.
Is there a nicer way to keep the focus within the Border (or a Grid,...)

I'm working on a Windows 8 App.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that using a [Modal Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `Form.ShowDialog(Owner)` still allows you to focus the parent components with Tab?

Can you give a sample of your code call?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm working on windows 8, added to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
Form2 form = new Form2(); //Make an instantiation of your Form
form.ShowDialog(); //ShowDialog()!!! NOT form.Show()!!! Or anything else :/
```

Comment: see comment on other answer (working with windows 8)

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- Set `Enabled` to `False` on the background visual tree, though that might change the way things look if you still want to show them partly
- Set `IsHitTestVisible` to `False` to disable pointer input
- Use `RenderTargetBitmap.Render()` if targeting Windows 8.1 to render the content of the background to an image and simply replace all that visual tree with an image of it